# Java script alert is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning JavaScript and HTML, and have created a webpage in which I have added a button, clicking on which should alert some words. But it is not giving the alert.Please help.Here's my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Pi^LaSa^
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" >
<!--
function developers(){
alert("The NaT Language was developed by Naman Chhaparia and Tanay Shankar,while sitting on the last bench of their former class 7 C while watching a boring dance practice !!
Naman and Tanay are best friends, and currently study at St. Thomas School, Ranchi,one of the best schools of the whole of Eastern-India. ")
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1><span style="font-size:28px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span style="color:#FF0000;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><strong>Pi<sup>^</sup></strong></span></span><span style="color:#40E0D0;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><strong>La</strong></span></span><span style="color:#00FF00;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><strong>Sa<sup>^</sup></strong></span></span></span></h1>

<h2><span style="font-size:28px;"><span style="color:#00FF00;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><strong><sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </sup></strong></span></span><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><strong><sup><span style="font-size: 14px;">( The official website of the NaT Language )</span></sup></strong></span></span></span></h2>

<p><span style="font-size:28px;"><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><span style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">Hello, guys !! Welcome to the official website of the NaT ( Pi<sup>^</sup>LaSa<sup>^</sup> ) language, which was developed by Naman Chhaparia (</span></span></span></span></span>Pi<sup>^</sup>LaPaLaPi&nbsp; Mi<sup>^</sup>NoNoLaTesLaMaLoLa) , and Tanay Shankar (Sa<sup>^</sup>LaPiLa Ax Ni<sup>^</sup>NoLaPiPoLaMa ).</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<input type="button" onclick="developers();" value="Learn about the Developers.">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So... You want us to write a language processing system for you?  Good luck with that.

Comment: No David , I just want to know how to do it. I surfed the net a lot for it, but in vain.

Comment: I vote to close this question as too broad.

Comment: Does anything at all happen when you click? Also I don't think you need the semicolon for the `onclick` attribute, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp).

Comment: Thanks SuperBiasedMan

Comment: Its working ,check properly the message present in alert().

Comment: I have modified your code ,please check it.Its so easy.

Answer (score 2):

Don't start writing simple scripts using long strings if you're not sure how use them. Start small and build on it.

Like this here: https://jsfiddle.net/9mhtdssk/1/

Keep it simple. your modified version of the code below:

```html
<html>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="developers();" value="Learn about the Developers.">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function developers() {
    alert('Simple small string of text');
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it.You have given extra spaces in alert.Its working.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Pi^LaSa^
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" >

            function developers() {
                alert("The NaT Language was developed by Naman Chhaparia and Tanay Shankar,while sitting on the last bench of their former class 7 C while watching a boring dance practice !! Naman and Tanay are best friends,and currently study at St. Thomas School, Ranchi,one of the best schools of the whole of Eastern-India.");

            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><span style="font-size:28px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span style="color:#FF0000;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><strong>Pi<sup>^</sup></strong></span></span><span style="color:#40E0D0;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><strong>La</strong></span></span><span style="color:#00FF00;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><strong>Sa<sup>^</sup></strong></span></span></span></h1>

        <h2><span style="font-size:28px;"><span style="color:#00FF00;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><strong><sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </sup></strong></span></span><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><strong><sup><span style="font-size: 14px;">( The official website of the NaT Language )</span></sup></strong></span></span></span></h2>

        <p><span style="font-size:28px;"><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><span style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">Hello, guys !! Welcome to the official website of the NaT ( Pi<sup>^</sup>LaSa<sup>^</sup> ) language, which was developed by Naman Chhaparia (</span></span></span></span></span>Pi<sup>^</sup>LaPaLaPi&nbsp; Mi<sup>^</sup>NoNoLaTesLaMaLoLa) , and Tanay Shankar (Sa<sup>^</sup>LaPiLa Ax Ni<sup>^</sup>NoLaPiPoLaMa ).</p>

        <p>&nbsp;</p>

        <input type="button" onclick="developers();" value="Learn about the Developers.">
    </body>
</html>
```